# How can I create a sorted list of integer and string pairs?

Tags: java

How can I create a list (or some other type of container) of integer and strings pairs that allows duplicates in both pairs and can be sorted by the integer value?

I need to fill a container with names (string) and scoring (integer) pairs, the container must allow duplicated values in both name and scoring, and i need to sort this list by the scoring value.

I tried with a SortedMap but doesn't allow duplicated values:

```
SortedMap<Integer,String> sm=new TreeMap<Integer, String>();

sm.put(23, "Peter");  
sm.put(11, "Tony");  
sm.put(110, "Claire");  
sm.put(13, "ferca");  
sm.put(55, "Julian");  
sm.put(13, "Pedro");
```

In this example, ferca and Pedro have the same scoring value, this is something I need to allow, but the SortedMap overwrites "ferca" with "Pedro".

What is the best container type to do this?

Comment: if you allow duplicate names how would you tell which two names apart?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since you want your collection to be ordered, I suggest you use a `List` and [`Collections.sort`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29). If you decide to go for this approach you still have two options:

- Create a custom `Comparator` that can be passed as an argument to [`sort`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29), or
- Let the auxiliary `Score` class implement `Comparable<Score>`

Here is an example and [ideone demo](http://ideone.com/ObdCY) of the latter approach:

```
import java.util.*;

class Score implements Comparable<Score> {
    int score;
    String name;

    public Score(int score, String name) {
        this.score = score;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Score o) {
        return score < o.score ? -1 : score > o.score ? 1 : 0;
    }
}

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        List<Score> scores = new ArrayList<Score>();

        scores.add(new Score(23, "Peter"));  
        scores.add(new Score(11, "Tony"));  
        scores.add(new Score(110, "Claire"));  
        scores.add(new Score(13, "ferca"));  
        scores.add(new Score(55, "Julian"));  
        scores.add(new Score(13, "Pedro"));

        Collections.sort(scores);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

1. Create a `class` that enclose these two field
2. create a custom [`Comparator`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) that compare two Objects based on int value.
3. Create a [`list`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) of that objects
4. [`Collection.sort();`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html)  pass obj of `comparator` here

   ```
   class MyEntity{
     int val;
     String name;
   }


   List<MyEntity> list = new ArrayList<MyEntity>();
   list.add(new MyEntity(1,"a"));
   list.add(new MyEntity(4,"z"));
   list.add(new MyEntity(2,"x"));
   Collections.sort(list,new MyComparator());


   class MyComparator implements Comparator<MyEntity>{
     public int compare(MyEntity ob1, MyEntity ob2){
      return ob1.getVal() - ob2.getVal() ;
     }
   }
   ```

Note: This is just model to show the basic idea

- [Here is working ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/tqngn)

Comment: I suggest you don't implement the raw Comparator interface and use `Comparator<MyEntity>` instead. It's more typesafe and you don't need to cast the arguments.

Comment: error: constructor MyEntity in class MyEntity cannot be applied to given types;
list.add(new MyEntity(1,"a"));

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a job for [Guava's](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) [Multimap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) types, specifically [TreeMultimap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/TreeMultimap.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you want a list, use a list...

The best option would probably be to create your own type to encapsulate the string and the integer, add your own comparison, and put them in an `ArrayList<T>`.

Sort it when you need to with `Collections.sort`.

If you don't need to allow duplicates which have the same name *and* score, you could use a `SortedSet` instead, so long as your comparison order sorts on both score *and* name.

Answer (score 0):

After you create a holding type, an alternative structure is [PriorityQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) to hold the items.  This differs from `Collections.sort()` because the items are inserted in order, with either the high or low values rising to the top.

The only thing you have to do is write a Comparator to pass onto the PriorityQueue on instanciation, so it knows to sort the items based on the integer value.

Both this method and `Collections.sort()` deliver the same results with different ways of going about it.  They also run in O(N log N) time.