# Java arrayList comparison

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

Could anybody tell me how to list some data in an arrayList according to the integer value that each component of the ArrayList has? This is my main class

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class StudentDriver {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Scanner scan, urlScan, fileScan;
    String url, file;
    int count = 0;
    scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the name of the file");
    fileScan = new Scanner(new File("Data.csv"));
    ArrayList<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();
        while(fileScan.hasNext()){
            url = fileScan.nextLine();
            urlScan = new Scanner(url);
            urlScan.useDelimiter(",");
            count++;
            while(urlScan.hasNext()){
                String name = urlScan.next();
                String last = urlScan.next();
                int score = urlScan.nextInt();
                Student e = new Student(name,last, score);
                studentList.add(e);

            }   
        }
        System.out.println("The file has data for" +count+ "instances");
        int option;
        do{

        System.out.println("********");
        System.out.println("Options:");
        System.out.println("********\n1. List \n2. Add Student \n3.Delete Student \n4. Exit \n******** ");
        System.out.print("Select option: ");
        option = scan.nextInt();

        if(option == 1){    
        int index = 0;
        while(index<studentList.size()){
            System.out.println(studentList.get(index));
            index++;
        }
        }
        else if(option == 2){
            System.out.print("Enter the name of the student: ");
            String newName = scan.next();
            System.out.print("Enter the last name of the student: ");
            String newLastName = scan.next();
            System.out.print("Enter the exam score of the student: ");
            int newScore = scan.nextInt();
            Student b = new Student(newName, newLastName, newScore);
            studentList.add(b);}
        else if(option == 3){
            System.out.print("Enter the name of the student to remove: ");
            String remove = scan.next();
            System.out.print("Enter the last name of the student: ");
            String remove1 = scan.next();
            int location = studentList.indexOf(remove);
            location = studentList.indexOf(remove1);

            studentList.remove(location);
            }   

        }while(option!=4 && option <4);
    }//main
}//class
```

And this is the other class

```
public class Student implements Comparable<Student>{
    String firstName, lastName;
    int score;

public Student(String firstName, String lastName, int score){
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.score = score;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public int getScore() {
    return score;
}

public void setScore(int score) {
    this.score = score;
}
public String toString(){
    return firstName + " " + lastName + ", exam score is "+ score;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Student c) {

    return score-c.getScore();
}
```

}

As you can see, up to now I have created the class where my compare method is but I have difficulties on using it. Also I have had difficulties on deleting one of the Array List parts by just writing the name and last name of the student. If somebody would help me, I would be very thankful.

Comment: Think about a Comparator.

Comment: If you need any more information about what I want to do just tell me.

Comment: Sounds like you want a TreeSet<Student>, not a List.

Comment: I am required to use an ArrayList(from my instructor). And I don't know how the TreeSet works btw

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create a sorted list of integer and string pairs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353572/how-can-i-create-a-sorted-list-of-integer-and-string-pairs)

Comment: I don't need more information; more effort on your part is what's required.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-  Also you shouldn't just substract 2 `int`s to get the result of `compareTo`. Although this may work if the scores are non-negative, you may get an overflow, if negative values are allowed. Better use `Integer.compare(int, int)`.

Comment: Since `Student` implements `Comparable`, creating a separate `Comparator` is redundant as `Student` already has a natural ordering that works the way it should. Just use [`Collections.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well you can change your compareTo method as

```
public int compareTo(Student another)
{
    if (this.score > another.score)
        return -1;
    if (this.score < another.score) 
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

this should show it as decreasing order you can change the operator

than use whereever you want to sort it

```
Collections.sort(studentList)
```

Also if you don't want to use Collections.sort() method I can show you how you can write it with for loop under add option

```
Student newStd = new Student(name, last, score);


                for(int i=0;studentList.size()>i;i++)
                {
                    int size = studentList.size();
                    if(newStd.compareToCustom(studentList.get(i))>0)
                    {
                        studentList.add(i, newStd);
                        break;
                    }
                    else if(newStd.compareToCustom(studentList.get(size-1))<0)
                    {
                        studentList.add(studentList.size(), newStd);
                        break;
                    }
                    else if(newStd.compareToCustom(studentList.get(i))==0)
                    {
                        studentList.add(i++, newStd);
                        break;
                    }
                }
```

for the remove part you can use

```
else if ( option == 3)
            {
                System.out.print("Enter the first name of student will be deleted: ");
                String removeName = scan.next();
                System.out.print("Enter the last name of student will be deleted: ");
                String removeLastName = scan.next();

                for ( int i = 0; i < studentList.size(); i++)
                {
                    Student deleted = studentList.get(i);

                    if ( deleted.getFirstName().toLowerCase().equals(removeName.toLowerCase()) && deleted.getLastName().toLowerCase().equals(removeLastName.toLowerCase()))
                    {
                        studentList.remove(i);
                        System.out.println("The student has been deleted.");
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("This student is not found");
                        break;
                    }

                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you want is an ordered collection. As @duffymo has stated, think about a creating a custom `Comparator` using your `score`.

There is plenty of info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353572/how-can-i-create-a-sorted-list-of-integer-and-string-pairs)

Answer (score 0):

In terms of deleting students from the list.
The `studentList` is a list containing `Student` objects. 
This means that the follow code:

```
System.out.print("Enter the name of the student to remove: ");
String remove = scan.next();
System.out.print("Enter the last name of the student: ");
String remove1 = scan.next();
int location = studentList.indexOf(remove);
```

Tries to find the index of a `Student` given the first name. This will return `-1` as you're searching for a `String` and not a `Student` object.
Instead you have to iterate through your `studentList` and compare the first and last name of each `Student` element with the values of `remove` and `remove1`.

```
for(Student student : studentList) {
    if(student.getFirstName.equals(remove) && student.getLastName.equals(remove1)) {
        // remove the student.
    }
}
```

Also you could consider giving each `Student` an ID as an unique identifier.

Comment: You won't be able to remove a student while iterating over studentList (concurrent modification exception).

Comment: Then save the index or something. The idea holds.

Answer (score 0):

try this to sort studentList

```
  Collections.sort(studentList, new Comparator<Student>() 
    {
        @Override
        public int compare(Student  x, Student  y)
        {
            if(x.score >= y.score)
                return 1;
            else 
                return -1;

        }
    });
```